# comparing the variance of the reparamatrization trick and the score function

Tags: statistics, optimization, estimation

I'm looking for the answers to the following questions:
Consider a single dimensional Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where we wish to estimate $\displaystyle E_{z\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)}[f(z)]$ for some differentiable function $f$.

(a) Show that the score function estimator of a single sample is $\frac{f(z)(x-\mu)}{\sigma^4}$.

(b) Show that the reparam estimator of a single sample is $f'(z)$.

(c) For each estimator show an example where it has lower variance than the other.

Additional info:

- The reparamatrization trick - in order to make a discrete variable a continuous one we will add a white noise $\varepsilon\sim(0,1)$ to the discrete variable.
- score function: $g(\theta) = \frac{\partial{log(f(\theta))}}{\partial{\theta}} $

  If you can please explain in which cases we will prefer to use each of the techniques mentioned above.

Comment: You have posted your question readable (Mathjax). That´s very nice. Maybe you have any idea about the score function. It would help people to start at this point.

Comment: Actually I don't really know where to start. I tried to calculate the derivative of log of normal distribution but it didn't help me.  Any other ideas?